# generating commands on terminal FROM Django after user submits data on webpage

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have made a simple Django webapp which takes two strings outputs from user in the form of CharField but those two strings need to be instantly run on terminal automatically with my "count.py" script to generate another webpage (which shows the result from my count.py script).

in terminal, command should be generated like this in backend after user submits data1 and data2 on webpage charfield:

```
count.py data1 data2
```

where data1, data2 comes from views.py after user hits the submit button on webpage. **I need to somehow write code which generates this terminal command by itself as soon as user hits submit button.**

Here is the code in my views.py

```
def fields (request):
    form = first_form(request.POST or None)
    data1 = request.POST.get('data1')
    data2 = request.POST.get('data2')

    if form.is_valid(): 
        #### how should i execute the arguments 
        'data1' and 'data2' run in terminal with my 
        'count.py' script #####

    return render(request, "first_page.html", {'form': form})
```

and here is the code for my count.py:

```
def count (a, b): 
    word = False 
    a = " " + a + " "
    b = " " + b + " "

    result = 0 

    for i in range (len (a)-1): 
        if a[i] == " " and a[i+1] != " ":
            word = True 
            result += 1
        else: 
            word = False
    for i in range (len (b)-1): 
        if b[i] == " " and b[i+1] != " ":
            word = True 
            result += 1
        else: 
            word = False


    return result
```

Comment: The specifics of how to create the script are out of the scope but try importing (import os) and then do os.system("command-in-here"). At least try it first on a simple .py file doing something like: import os...os.system("echo $HOME").

Comment: Why you need to run count.py code from terminal? You should run that code from views not from commands

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['python', 'count.py', 'whatever'])
```

However, I think count should be part of some Model and you should call it in your view

Comment: yes, i also feel that count.py should be called in views.py. lemme try that and get back on if it works or not. Thank you, Sir! :)

Comment: how can I make count.py part of models.py and then call it views.py?

Comment: suprocess.Popen can take a list of python files and strings all together? count.py takes two arguments which are strings: data1 and data2 in terminal

Comment: I suggest you do the Model View approach. If you don't want to write all the code in the same file just import it at the top then.